# CreateJS Sprite Animation Issue. During animation Sprite frames are moving from left to right

Tags: jquery, animation, javascript, createjs

I've been working with createJS lately and i ran into a problem with Sprite Animations. The problem is that while animation is running the frames are changing correctly but they are moving from constantly from left to right instead of staying in fixed position. Here is a demo of my task and what the problem exactly is, pay attention to the explosion animation.

http://mariokirilov.softuni-friends.org/

Here is a little code to show how exactly I created the Sprite.

```
function startAnimation () {
var explosionSpritesheet = new createjs.SpriteSheet({
    'images': [preloader.getResult('explosion')],
    'frames': {width:120, height:127, count:40, spacing:0, margin:0},
    'animations': {
        'explode': [0,39,true]
    }
});
var explosion = new createjs.Sprite(explosionSpritesheet);
explosion.width = 127;
explosion.height = 127;

stage.addChild(explosion);
explosion.gotoAndPlay('explode');
createjs.Ticker.addEventListener('tick', tickHandler);
}

function tickHandler (e) {
    stage.update();
}
```

Comment: It looks like the images you're using to create the sprite are not the same dimensions as the sprite itself.

Comment: I see a small aerial view of a figure, whom I can rotate 360 degrees, but nothing moves left to right.

Comment: On left-click it shoots. And the explosion of the rockets is the problem.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan can u tell me how I can fix this problem. Are u talking about the size of the image and the sprite ?

Comment: The code you posted here contains the correct dimensions for the sprite. But I see different code on that link in a file called "game.js". The dimensions specified there are not correct.

Comment: I fixed it, it was from the dimensions of the sprite.I made it from 127 to 128 and it worked. Thanks a lot guys !